# Set the custom CI config path in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab

Gitlab uses the custom CI config path for the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file in the root of the project. However, I would like to set it to the project location of `build/ci/.gitlab-ci.yml`.

How do I set the path and can I do it inside the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file itself?

I know we can set the path in the Gitlab CI/ CD settings page but I look for a programmable solution so we don't need to enter there (and put it by hand.)

Comment: You can't set the path of the file inside the file, because whatever's reading the file needs to know the path of the file to read the file to get the path of the file to read the file to get the path of the file to...

Comment: @jonrsharpe that is true. If I was able to express properly, I look for any programmable solution to set the path so I don't need to go in the Gitlab settings. I was even looking for the `python-gitlab` to login and do so. 

So any solution that works is fine.

Comment: Er - just [`include`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#include) your other file in the main one surely?

Comment: Boris what do you mean?

Comment: Did you follow the link? You can have a stub `.gitlab-ci.yml` in the root directory that `include`s the file from `/build/ci`, or wherever else you want.

Comment: I just find that is a link and helps to solve the problem.